regex negative lookahead how to find a string that ends with a series of digits and a parenthesis?
I have this regex for Notepad++ which works to find the strings I am supposed to find which are all lines ending each with a number in brackets.
^.*\(\d*\)\r\n
Problem is:
Those are the lines I want to keep with a regex find & replace where I erase the other lines.
I tried
^.*?(?!\(\d*\))\r\n
^.*?(?!(\(\d*\)))\r\n
(?!(^.*?\(\d*\)\r\n))

None of these seem to work (or not work correctly).
What am I doing wrong?

welcome to stackoverflow Simone! any example of the lines in question? sample input would be nice to explore.

I think this regex should only capture lines that does not end with numbers with parenthesis at the end:
^(?!.*\(\d+\)$).*$

Demo

^ asserts position at start of a line
(?!.*\(\d+\)$) negative look ahead to see if the line not ends with
number inside parenthesis.
.* mathces the full line
$ asserts position at the end of a line


Thanks! This worked. I was just not thinking about repeating the query after the lookahead. I thought it was needed only before of it, for some reason. Me dumb. Cannot upvote because I do not have reputation, but... uh.... you have my ghostly +1.
